# How do you GoTo a line label in a different object?

Tags: excel, vba

E.g. Given Sheet 1 contains:

`Ref: Do things`

How can I direct a code in Module 1 to `GoTo Ref`? If I were in the `Sheet1` code moduke then I could simply use a 
`Goto Ref`

But this doesn't work across different modules

Comment: I think you are going to have to tidy up that question and perhaps add a tag for the application.

Comment: Not possible. Anyway you shouldn't use `GoTo` unless you absolutely have to, which is almost never.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To help expand on the other answers.. Like they said you shouldn't use GoTo for anything in VBA except error handling.

What you should be doing is calling a public sub/function from another module. For example in Module 1 you would have the following

```
Sub TestMod1()
Dim MyNumber As Integer

MyNumber = GetSquare(6)
'MyNumber returns from the function with a value of 36
End Sub
```

and on Module 2 you have

```
Public Function GetSquare(ByVal MyNumber As Integer)

GetSquare = MyNumber * MyNumber

End Function
```

So now you know how to avoid it. GoTo is not very good programming practice as you'll have things flying all over the place. Try to break down code you're repeating into multiple Subs and just call them when needed, or functions whatever be the case. Then you'll get into classes, which are just wrapped up to represent an object and it'll do all the work for that object.

This should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is not clear and you didn't provide any code, so this is a guess.

**GoTo** is used to jump to different locations within the same sub/function. You cannot use it to jump to parts of other sub routines or functions, which it sounds like you might be trying to do.

Also, "NapDone:" is not called a reference, it's formally called a **line label**. :)

Comment: Thanks - new here. I got around it by created a series of subroutines in Sheet1 that contained a GoTo and then pointing to those subs from the Module.

Comment: No problem and welcome! If my answer (or anyone else's) is a suitable answer, please select the arrow that appears at the upper left of it to 'accept' the answer. As Jean-Francois Corbett mentioned in his comment, GoTo statements are rarely needed and usually represent an opportunity to rework the logic in the routines.